# Enumerize in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enumerize

I am trying to use Enumerize for attributes I defined.

in my Student Model

```
extend Enumerize
attr_accessor :order_by

enumerize :order_by, in: %w[time grade school], i18n_scope: "order_by_options"
```

in my view (which is part of a form_tag)

```
<%= label_tag t("order_by") %>
<%= select_tag :order_by, Student.order_by.options, class: 'form-control' %>
```

But the options are not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `#options` is suitable argument for `#select` (it's an array), while for `#select_tag` you should make a string with option tags, either manually or by using `#options_for_select` [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select).